# Windows Authentication in SQL Sever 2000 for an account not logged into Windows

Tags: sql-server, odbc, windows-authentication

An advantage by using Windows Authentication is that I do not need to provide a username and password to log into the server as the user currently logged into Windows. But in a specific case I would like to log into the SQL Server as another user, using the same Windows Authenticated ODBC connection.

So, the question: Is it possible to log into an SQL Server using Windows Authentication, but not as the user currently logged into Windows (without a dialog asking for username and password)?

Comment: This is typically the kind of question that arises when some things begins to go wrong with the system (being database, security or application issues). Can you be more explicit on this "specific case"?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is no, without a dialog being presented, it's not possible to login to SQL Server using another Windows account.

The slightly more complex answer is; You can login as another user (WITH a dialog being presented) by right-clicking the Query Analyser icon and choosing "Run As" (Might require a CTRL or SHIFT key held down to make RUN AS appear.

There's also the RUNAS command line executable which you could look at, so you could create a shortcut that contains the RUNAS command, the credentials and the path to Query Analyser. That would eliminate being asked for a username or password on execution.

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, if you are not using the credentials of the logged in user, you will need to pass other credentials--short of asking for them directly, the only other option is to store them..

And once you are doing that, it may be worth considering mixed-mode authentication and use SQL login/pw for this specific situation.

Comment: We do have the username and password stored.

As it seems the ODBC DSN decides if SQL authentication or Windows authentication should be used, we're trying to avoid having twice as many ODBC DSNs, one for each.

Comment: L. Kolmodin: You can build your ODBC connection string "on the fly", and programmatically change the connection's property such as uid, pwd, or trusted_connection. There is no need to maintain multiple DSNs for that

Answer (score 0):

Runas does not let you provide a password on the command line and will produce a popup to gather it.  A little searching let me to an artical on technet that may help out while not it's intended use..

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727155.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/29/271551.aspx

Comment: Ahh, does it not? The syntax for EPAL doesn't look familiar to me, but I guess there's more than one tool out there that does the same thing. It must have been a home-grown "RUNAS" tool I was using at my previous employers.